# How to generate a PHP array from MySQL database record for multi-level folder structure

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, menu

I am wanting to build an Evernote style note app with PHP and MySQL.

Evernote allows top level folders with note records in them.

I would like to make my app allow folders to be inside of folders so a top level folder can have a child folder which then has note records inside of the child folder.

Like this image below:

[image]

---

I have this PHP function which will build the structure menu shown in the image above...

This code build the menu shown

```
<?php
function tree($array, $parent, $parts = array(), $step = 0) {

    if (!count($array)) {
        return '';
    }

    $tid = ($step == 0) ? 'id="tree"' : '';
    $t = '<ul class="unstyled" '.$tid.'>';

    foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
        if (is_array($item)) {
            $open = $step !== false && (isset($parts[$step]) && $key == $parts[$step]);

            $t .= '<li class="directory'. ($open ? ' open' : '') .'">';
                $t .= '<a href="#" data-role="directory"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-'. ($open ? 'open' : 'close') .'"></i>&nbsp; ' . $key . '</a>';
                $t .= tree($item, "$parent/$key", $parts, $open ? $step + 1 : false);
            $t .=  '</li>';
        } else {
            $selected = (isset($parts[$step]) && $item == $parts[$step]);
            $t .= '<li class="file'. ($selected ? ' active' : '') .'"><a href="'. $parent .'/'. $item . '">'.$item.'</a></li>';
        }
    }

    $t .= '</ul>';

    return $t;
}
?>
```

---

The code above build the tree menu by calling `_getTree()`

```
protected function _getTree($dir = LIBRARY)
{
    $return = array('directories' => array(), 'files' => array());

    $items = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if(preg_match($this->_ignore, $item)) {
            if($this->_force_unignore === false || !preg_match($this->_force_unignore, $item)) {
                continue;
            }
        }

        $path = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $item;
        if (is_dir($path)) {
            $return['directories'][$item] = $this->_getTree($path);
            continue;
        }

        $return['files'][$item] = $item;
    }

    uksort($return['directories'], "strnatcasecmp");
    uksort($return['files'], "strnatcasecmp");

    return $return['directories'] + $return['files'];
}
```

---

`_getTree()` above builds an array in the format shown below by scanning directories on server looking for folders and files.  It then passes that array into `tree()`.  My goal is to make a function build this same style array but from MySQL Database folder and note records.

I need to write a function that could build array like below from two database tables.

MY database tables will be

- **notebooks** with column name `parent` to denote the parent folder.  THe notebook ID will go into parent field if the notebook is a child folder of a parent notebook.  0 == parent level folder.
- **notes** with `parent` column to be linked to ID of notebook.

Code:

```
Array(
    [top_level_notebook_1] => Array(
            [child_note_of_parent_notebook_1.html] => some_note.html
            [child_level_notebook_1] => Array(
                    [note_1.html] => some_note.html
            )

            [child_level_notebook_2] => Array(
                    [note_2] => cache.js
                    [note_3] => cache.js.md
                    [note_4] => Confirmation-Dialog.js
            )

            [child_level_notebook_3] => Array(
                    [crud.php] => crud.php
                    [error2mysql.php] => error2mysql.php
                    [upload_file_from_remote_url.php] => upload_file_from_remote_url.php
            )

    )

    [top_level_notebook_2] => Array(
            [note_7.html] => some_note.html
    )

    [root_level_note.html] => Dev_Bookmarks.html
)
```

Comment: Hmm.. Is this asking for an opinion on how to structure your database or once you have done that how to query it?

Comment: @BobNocraz On how to query it.  I updated question to show DB structure with parent columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to get incredibly complex with your query, I'd do something more along the lines of getting all records and building an array with your script. Something like this:

Script now including the Database stuff (**Updated**):

```
//Change these credentials!
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT nb.`name` AS 'notebook', no.`name` AS 'note', (SELECT `name` FROM `notebooks` WHERE `id` = nb.`parent`) AS 'nbparent', no.`parent` AS 'noparent' FROM `notebooks` nb RIGHT JOIN `notes` no ON no.`parent` = nb.`id` WHERE (nb.`active` = 1 OR nb.`active` IS NULL) AND (no.`active` = 1 OR no.`active` IS NULL)";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);

$myArray = array();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    if($row['nbparent']){
        if($row['note']) $myArray[$row['nbparent']][$row['notebook']][] = $row['note'];
    } else {
        if($row['note']) {
            if($row['notebook']) $myArray[$row['notebook']][] = $row['note'];
                else $myArray[] = $row['note'];
        }

    }

}

var_dump($myArray);
```

This should work! I tested it on my local dev environment and got this result with a set of test data:

```
array (size=4)
  'Parent Notebook1' => 
    array (size=6)
      0 => string 'Note1' (length=5)
      1 => string 'Note2' (length=5)
      2 => string 'Note5' (length=5)
      'Child Notebook1' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'Note6' (length=5)
      'Child Notebook2' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'Note7' (length=5)
      'Child Notebook3' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'Note8' (length=5)
  'Parent Notebook2' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'Note3' (length=5)
  'Parent Notebook3' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'Note4' (length=5)
  0 => string 'Note With No Parent :(' (length=22)
```

What that's doing is looping through each result. Surely you'll need to change the column names, like in $row['notebook'], to what your actual column is named. It'll work one-level deep. If you need more, you'll have to tweak a bit. This is the general idea, though, and should get an array built from your structure.

**Quick Note**

The code above will not be **strict-friendly**. If you're concerned with warnings, the above code will give you warnings about undefined keys. It'll create them for you, as we've all grown to love/hate about PHP. If you want to keep the key warnings out, you can easily pop in some key checks with `if(array_key_exists())`.

**Potential 'Gotcha'**

This works on names. If you allow the same name for 'notebooks', I'd suggest taking it a step further and building the array by id rather than a text-based column like the title of your notebook. From there, you'll need to add a new key inside of each notebook with the name itself. I replicated the array you provided in your example when making this script, but I did want to be absolutely sure you understood the potential (frustrating) "gotcha" involved with this method.

Let me know if you have any questions, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, my database exist only in my head at the moment so I will set up a test and report back.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem, hope it helps! Let me know if this doesn't quite solve your needs and I'll edit my answer :)

Comment: This image shows my test results... https://www.apollowebstudio.com/screenshots/2016/chrome_2016-02-11_18-15-22.png and my sample DB http://pastebin.com/xChA7Btj

Comment: Do you already have your script getting a dataset from your database using this query?

Comment: Actually I don't really have anything yet except the test DB I just made.  Changes can go anyway needed for best results at this point to get desired output of notebook folder that allow child notes and child notebooks

Comment: The code has been updated - see if this fits your needs :)

Comment: Here is my updated result with child notes under a child notebook https://www.apollowebstudio.com/screenshots/2016/chrome_2016-02-11_19-03-27.png

Comment: It looks like it is close to what I need but will need some tweaking still.  Couple issues: 1) child notebooks only show if they have a child note and they should actually show all notes and notebooks in the menu structure.  2) child notebook starts a new separate array under the parent from the child notes.  I think the notes and notebooks should be combined into the same array instead of notes being separate array from the notebooks.  Any thoughts?  Thanks so much for your efforts so far!

Comment: I am wondering if I might even be better off to make 2 separate MySQL queries.  1 for notebooks and 1 for notes and then build the array from both those result loops?  I see what your SQL does now, it returns a record foir each Note and hows what parent notebook the note belongs to and also the parent notebook that the notes parent notebook belongs to.  This would work great now If I can get the PHP to properly build the structure from this data in which it would need to show the child notebooks  as a new level and indent the child notes that are under child notebooks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103244/discussion-between-nate-i-and-jasondavis).

Comment: Hey I been busy the past couple days I am just now seeing this.  You got it working great from what I can tell so far.  I had pretty much given up on the single query concept as 95% of my Google searches show this exact type of functionality when used for Categories, Tags, Menus with sub-menus, etc.... it showed they all used a recursive function and and many had 2 queries........continue.....

Comment: ....continued.....This is the first time I have seen this done in this manner where it doesn't even use a recursive function!  That's pretty interesting.  Also most others only had to deal with 1 type of entity, like a category as a parent or child category and in this case there are 2 types.  Notebook and Note.  SO thanks a bunch for taking the time to help with this, im impressed and happy with the results and I am certain it will help others for years to come on SO! Thanks again

Comment: Also plugging the result array right into the `tree()` method in my question above has my desired output shown in this image https://www.apollowebstudio.com/screenshots/2016/chrome_2016-02-14_22-11-31.png  -  You mentioned it will work for **one level deep** but in the image here it appear it might be working for more than 1 level am I right?

Comment: Hey @JasonDavis, I'm glad it's working for you, that's great! I apologize on my terminology, I meant one sub-directory when I said one level deep. So if you had a Notebook with the parent of `Child Notebook 2` for example, it wouldn't list it or any notes with that third-level Notebook as its parent. 

Making it truly recursive wouldn't take much work at all, though. Is that something you'd need?

Comment: Thanks, honestly I am on the fence if I need it or not but if it is a quick fix would love to see it as an alternative.  If you feel like doing it could maybe update answer to show current way and that way.  Would be awesome thanks again for the help